# Formatting a String for a name in java

Tags: java, string, title-case

How do I change the case of the first character in a string that has multiple words? For example:

> First Last

to

> first last

or

> The Fat Cat Is Hungry

to

> the fat cat is hungry

Answer (score 3):

> [**toLowerCase**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)
>
> ```
> public String toLowerCase()
> ```
>
> Converts all of the characters in this String to lower case using the
>   rules of the default locale.
>
> Returns: the String, converted to lowercase.

Next time, search the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) first.

Answer (score 1):

In java ?

```
result = changeCase.toLowerCase( )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like that:

```
String result = yourstring.toLowerCase( );
```